# How to execute js with Jade?

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs

i was wondering how to execute js before rendering?

**This fails**

```
-#{somejs} // Outputs just the js-code
p #{somejs()} // Executes the js-code, but doenst render the html
```

// In EJS I just write. But how can i do this with node?

```
<%- somejs() %>
```

// I try to use express-messasges (https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages) with Jade instead of ejs

Comment: If the processing is complex, wouldn't it be better to execute your javascript before rendering the jade template? Such as, in the route that calls `res.render()`. For simple things like alternate row colouring calculations, inline `- blah()` does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following both work for me:

```
- var test = Math.sqrt(16);
  div #{test}
```

or

`div #{Math.sqrt(25)}`

If possible, would you please post your `somejs()`? Are you certain that it is producing a HTML string?

Answer (score 3):

To use [express-messages](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages) with [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) use this code in your template:

```
- var m = messages()
!= m
```

Answer (score 2):

In jade simply use `- someJS()` for more example see the jade [website](http://jade-lang.com/) and the in the [readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme)

Comment: BTW: I try to use express-messasges (https://github.com/visionmedia/express-messages) with Jade instead of ejs