# Where exactly did circular reference start when JSON.stringify throws the error?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug, circular-reference

Passing an object to `JSON.stringify` throws the error "Converting circular structure to JSON" but I'm not exactly sure why.

I'm passing the object via server-side node.js

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index.jade', {object: object});
});
```

to Jade

```
script var table = !{JSON.stringify(object)};
```

And it's throwing the error when Jade tries to parse the `object`.

But I have no reason to believe `object` have circular references. Infact I do a

```
console.info(JSON.stringify(req.user.table.export))
```

right before `res.render` and it works fine!

[image]

Is there a way to know precisely where did the circular reference come into being?

**edit** [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/1266650), but unfortunately [can't use it in Jade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZLfb.png).

**edit2** [actually can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786674/how-to-execute-js-with-jade)

Answer (score 0):

In Jade

```
- var cache = [];
script var table = !{JSON.stringify(table,function(key, value) {if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {console.log('Found Circular reference: '+key);return;}cache.push(value);}return value;})};
- cache = null;
```

output

> {"players":[{"id":"53179fd401d540b8c5000001","username":...
>   Found Circular reference: table
>   connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() m
>   Found Circular reference: owner
>   Found Circular reference:
>   Found Circular reference: sockets
>   Found Circular reference: store
>   Found Circular reference: manager
>   Found Circular reference: manager
>   Found Circular reference: mime
>   Found Circular reference: mime
>   Found Circular reference: mime
>   Found Circular reference: mime
>   Found Circular reference: user
>   Found Circular reference: user
>   Found Circular reference: _idleNext
>   Found Circular reference: _idlePrev
>   Found Circular reference: _idleNext
>   Found Circular reference: j1sYyxSoI8LEw5DNYGUa
>   Found Circular reference: manager
>   Found Circular reference: store
>   Found Circular reference: table

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/1266650)

no idea why it's happening though... ([link to issue on /Jade github](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1502))

Comment: If you want to restore the circular reference when parsing the JSON try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23961876/2464634)